# BlueCove with Bluez chucks "Can not open SDP session. [2] No such file or directory"

Tags: java, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to write a simple Bluetooth server that accepts an connection from my HeartRate-Device (bluetooth LE) but it always raises an exception

```
javax.bluetooth.ServiceRegistrationException: Can not open SDP session. [2] No such file or directory
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ.openSDPSessionImpl(Native Method) ~[bluecove-gpl-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-63.jar:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ.getSDPSession(BluetoothStackBlueZ.java:518) ~[bluecove-gpl-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-63.jar:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ.registerSDPRecord(BluetoothStackBlueZ.java:543) ~[bluecove-gpl-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-63.jar:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ.rfServerOpen(BluetoothStackBlueZ.java:607) ~[bluecove-gpl-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-63.jar:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothRFCommConnectionNotifier.<init>(BluetoothRFCommConnectionNotifier.java:42) ~[bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-63.jar:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.intel.bluetooth.MicroeditionConnector.openImpl(MicroeditionConnector.java:389) ~[bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-63.jar:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.intel.bluetooth.MicroeditionConnector.open(MicroeditionConnector.java:156) ~[bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-63.jar:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(Connector.java:83) ~[bluecove-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-63.jar:2.1.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.mmazurcz.bluetoothserver.WaitThread.waitForConnection(WaitThread.java:39) [classes/:na]
at com.mmazurcz.bluetoothserver.WaitThread.run(WaitThread.java:60) [classes/:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

I am running my code on an Arch Linux machine with kernel "4.0.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT".

Java is OpenJDK at version 1.8.0_45 and Bluecove is at version 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-63. I've got the following BlueZ artifacts installed:

1. bluez 5.30-1
2. bluez-firmware 1.2-8
3. bluez-libs 5.30-1
4. bluez-utils 5.30-1

The Bluetooth dongle I am using is up and running and I can scan for my heart-rate device using `hcitool -i hci0 lescan`. I am also running my code as the root user.

So, here is the piece of code that brings me trouble:

```
StreamConnectionNotifier notifier;
StreamConnection connection = null;

// setup the server to listen for connection
try {
    local = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
    log.info("Set up local device with BT address: " + local.getBluetoothAddress());
    local.setDiscoverable(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC);
    log.info("Set local device to GIAC discovery mode");

    UUID uuid = new UUID("1101", true);
    String url = "btspp://localhost:" + uuid.toString() + ";name=RemoteBluetooth";
    notifier = (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open(url);
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Exception in WaitThread.waitForConnection", e);
    return;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked and fulfiled the requirements described here? http://www.bluecove.org/bluecove-gpl/index.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First: I know this is a rather old post, but I got here quite often through Google and I finally got it working on my machine.

To got it working we need to start the bluetooth daemon with the `-C` (or `--compat`) option. This is done by making the following change:

Open a terminal and enter

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.target.wants/bluetooth.service
```

then change line

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

to

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -C
```

(simply adding the `-C` option)

Now you need to restart the system daemons:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And finally restart the Bluetooth service:

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

I found this solution here: [RaspberryPi Forum: Bluetooth RFCOMM - Jessie](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=125922)

Hope I could still help someone!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use libraries that don't need a deprecated interface?

Comment: Yes, but BlueCove and AvetanaBluetooth were about the only libs back then you really found and this did work after all. Also, this post is four years old :)

Comment: so would you please kindly have a look at https://askubuntu.com/q/1273074/778232 ? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help you with that. I haven't used BT since back then and I'm simply not interested in getting involved with it again.

Comment: "and I'm simply not interested in getting involved with it again." Lucky you ;-) . Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem for few days now, I followed Cyphargs instruction but then I got new problem, it says permission denied instead of saying no such file or directory, then i found the magic solution on [Arch Linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=201672) :

```
chmod 777 /var/run/sdp  # this line has done the magic
```