# BlueCove cannot connect do Device "Permission Denied [13]"

Tags: java, exception, bluetooth, bluecove

I am trying to connect to a bluetooth device, which i can pair to when setting the target device in pair mode, but trying to reconnect with the following method causes errors.
The Code that causes it:

```
StreamConnection streamConnection = null;
        try {
            streamConnection = (StreamConnection)Connector.open("btspp://A0E6F8FECB26:1;authenticate=false;encrypt=false;master=false");
            callback.onSocketCreated(streamConnection);
            callback.onConnectionSucceed();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The Exception That occurs

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect. [13] Permission denied
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ.connectionRfOpenClientConnectionImpl(Native Method)
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothStackBlueZ.connectionRfOpenClientConnection(BluetoothStackBlueZ.java:574)
at com.intel.bluetooth.BluetoothRFCommClientConnection.<init>(BluetoothRFCommClientConnection.java:37)
at com.intel.bluetooth.MicroeditionConnector.openImpl(MicroeditionConnector.java:379)
at com.intel.bluetooth.MicroeditionConnector.open(MicroeditionConnector.java:162)
at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(Connector.java:83)
at insight.utils.ConnectionEstablisher.run(ConnectionEstablisher.java:170)
```

I have to use Java and this is the only Library I found (That somewhat works) for this purpose:

```
BlueCove version 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT on bluez
```

I am on Arch Linux with the newest bluez Version and I have already tried [This Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946821/bluecove-with-bluez-chucks-can-not-open-sdp-session-2-no-such-file-or-direct?rq=1) to no avail.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially, the issue was the entire Bluetooth Stack / how it propagates "pairing requests" to the  Bluetooth Stack.

As a sidenote I was using BlueZ (5.56) on Arch Linux and the bluecove library for Java.

I was looking into alternative Bluetooth Stacks and thought about trying the same code on Windows 10, which doesnt use the BlueZ Stack.

Windows then popped up a window where it asked if i wanted to pair to this device.

This was the main difference between Windows and Linux.
Windows / its bluetooth stack or whatever is responsible for it, actually registered the device as "paired".

This then allowed me to re-connect to the device without any "Permission Denied" issues.

Hope this helps anyone that has to deal with this library or has similar issues.